# actionscript 3 add and remove movieclip button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript

Trying to make buttons on actionscript: create and remove movieclip object, but always some errors...
I need one button creates movieclip, another must to delete it by mouse click. Here is code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;

main.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);
function addMain(e: MouseEvent) {
    var movieClip: bm = new bm();
    movieClip.x = 640;
    movieClip.y = 570;
    this.addChild(movieClip);
    main.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);
    deletemain.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);
}

deletemain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteMain);
function deleteMain(e: MouseEvent)  {
    var movieClip: bm = bm(event.target);
    this.removeChild(movieClip);
    removeChild(movieClip);
    movieClip = null;
    deletemain.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteMain);
}
```

Comment: If you have errors, you should obviously post them. They provide helpful information on how to get rid of them, after all, that's why you receive them.

Comment: Ok, I didnt knew it, first time here.

Comment: But not your first time explaining something. Always provide all the related information that you have. If you do not understand them, that's ok and can be part of the question. I didn't downvote your question, but chances are somebody did for that reason. If you include all relevant information your questions are received better by the community and are more likely answered. Btw, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to understand why your code is not working, let's take a look on it :

```
main.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);
function addMain(e: MouseEvent) 
{
    // here you are creating a local var "movieClip" 
    // inside your "addMain" function, so it's only accessible here
    var movieClip:bm = new bm();
        movieClip.x = 640;
        movieClip.y = 570;

    this.addChild(movieClip);

    main.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);

    // I don't really know why you do this !
    deletemain.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addMain);
}

deletemain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteMain);
function deleteMain(e: MouseEvent)
{
    // here, you are creating a local var "movieClip"
    // by casting (converting) your "deletemain" button (e.target) to an "bm" object

    // event.target should be e.target
    var movieClip: bm = bm(event.target);

    // here your are removing the "deletemain" button, once
    this.removeChild(movieClip);
    // and twice
    removeChild(movieClip);

    movieClip = null;

    deletemain.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteMain);
}
```

So to do what you want : creating a MovieClip and removing it using two buttons, you have to declare your "movieClip" as a global var to be accessible for your two listener functions :

```
// declare a global "bm" object
var movieClip:bm;

btn_add.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_add_onPress);
function btn_add_onPress(e: MouseEvent): void
{
    // create the "movieClip" object
    movieClip = new bm();
    addChild(movieClip);

    // remove the click event listener for the btn_add
    btn_add.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_add_onPress);
}

btn_delete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_delete_onPress);
function btn_delete_onPress(e:MouseEvent) : void 
{
    // remove the "movieClip" object
    removeChild(movieClip);
    movieClip = null;

    // remove the click event listener for the btn_delete
    btn_delete.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_delete_onPress);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Excellent @akmozo!!! Thank you very much for your help! Its hard to me understand actionscript...

Comment: @AlexBulava You are welcome. Take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) for more about learning ActionScript 3.